# Set up Outlook not to use .ost file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to set up Outlook not to use .ost file? It's terribly large, in my case about 6,5 GB and it's causing problems on my system drive. If I understand it correctly, the only purpose of this file is to store the mailbox on disk, which is something I really don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn Outlook Exchange Cache OFF.  Here is an article to do that.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c#:~:text=Turn%20on%20or%20off%20Cached%20Exchange%20Mode&text=Click%20Account%20Settings%2C%20and%20then,Cached%20Exchange%20Mode%20check%20box](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c#:%7E:text=Turn%20on%20or%20off%20Cached%20Exchange%20Mode&text=Click%20Account%20Settings%2C%20and%20then,Cached%20Exchange%20Mode%20check%20box).

> Turn Cached Exchange Mode on or off Click File > Account Settings >
> Account Settings. Account Settings in the Backstage view Click the
> Exchange or Microsoft 365, and then click Change.

Use the settings when you click Change to turn Cache (OST) On or OFF.

Here is another helpful article on OST files including later converting them to PST files

https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/how-to/disable-ost-file.html

Comment: Unfortunately the option was obviously removed from Outlook, which is pretty annoying. All I can do is to set Outlook to keep the offline mails for only a month. I hope it will make the file smaller.

Comment: If you wish to invest (a small amount), you can convert the offline mails to a PST file and keep those. That will ensure you have your emails in a good file.

Comment: How would that help with a drive space? It's just another file.

Comment: True, but I thought you might like the PST files over time. They would not be large, of course.